# Any disadvantages to using spring to separate tests and data?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit

I've been struggling coming up with a good solution to separate my testing data from unit
 tests (hard coded values).  Until it dawned on me that I could create beans with spring 
and use those beans to hold my data.

Are there any draw backs to coding my unit tests this way?  Albeit they run a bit slower
 seeing as how spring has to configure all the beans and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine practice - one of the prime motivators for *dependency injection* in my view (easier to unit test)

It will be slower because of the need to bring up the Spring application context, so you might reserve this technique for "integration tests".

Answer (score 2):

For unit tests you can always wire in your beans by hand, as in create and inject them yourself, then leave the Spring wiring for integration tests and production/development.